# Check for None in Scala Option type isEmpty method

Tags: scala, scala-option

I'm using the Option Type's `isEmpty` method to check if there is no value. I do not want to use the `case` `match` as in my situation, I just want to check if there is `None` as I would throw an error to the caller. But the `isEmpty` method fails even though the value is `None`.

Here is what I tried!

```
val questionOption = Question.getQuestionForQuestionId(userExam.get.examId, currQuesId + 1)

if(questionOption.isEmpty) {
    Left(Failure(FailureCode.NO_DATA_FOUND, "Cannot get next exam question you tampered your cookie or cookie is lost.... >> TODO... modify the exception message"))
}
```

It is not getting inside the if condition. I tried to do a println on the questionOption and it prints None. So wondering why I'm not getting inside the if condition.

Comment: Can you show some code replicating this issue?

Comment: `case object None extends Option[Nothing] { def isEmpty = true; ...}`

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong or the description of the problem is misleading. If you will paste None.isEmpty into the REPL it will return true.

Comment: val questionOption = Question.getQuestionForQuestionId(userExam.get.examId, currQuesId + 1)

      if(questionOption.isEmpty) {
        Left(Failure(FailureCode.NO_DATA_FOUND, "Cannot get next exam question you tampered your cookie or cookie is lost.... >> TODO... modify the exception message"))
      }

Comment: What do you mean with "isEmpty method fails"? isEmpty return true for None, as opposite as isDefined: perhaps you got confused?

Comment: The call to Question.getQuestionForQuestionId(userExam.get.examId, currQuesId + 1) returns None! I verified that as well with a println statement.

Comment: What I noticed is that it is getting inside the if condition but I'm returning from inside the if condition. The return type of the method is an Either. How come it is not returning? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Ok, what happens next? even if the condition is verified the function return is not that...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the comment under the question, the real problem emerges:

```
 val questionOption = Question.getQuestionForQuestionId(userExam.get.examId, currQuesId + 1) 
 if(questionOption.isEmpty) { 
   Left(Failure(FailureCode.NO_DATA_FOUND, "Cannot get next exam question you tampered your cookie or cookie is lost.... >> TODO... modify the exception message")) 
 }
```

By itself, `if` returns type `Unit` so that your statement is returning nothing useful. If you want to return something you need to add in either an `else` which then returns the least upper bound of the result types. Hence

```
 >>> val yo = if(1 != 0) 4
 yo: Unit

 >>> val ya = if(1 != 0) Left(1) else Right("got it")
 ya: Either[Int, String]
```

Answer (score 15):

You could just do a boolean check to see of the value is None and throw the error to the caller if it is, otherwise continue processing:

```
scala> val o: Option[Any] = None
o: Option[Any] = None

scala> println(o == None)
true

scala> println(o != None)
false
```

But maybe a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do, alert the caller of the error or continue processing, would be to use Scala's [Try](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html) idiom to handle errors.